# P2V with rsync :

Tags: redhat, physical-to-virtual

I am trying to create a vmware virtual machine from a physical one running RedHat. Here are the steps I followed:

I create a VM and boot a live-cd (kali). I perform a rsync of the physical host for its `/` without the `proc`, `sys` and `dev` folders. I launch the VM, starting on kali, and partition `/dev/sda` to get a `/dev/sda1`. I create a `ext4` filesystem on it and mount it on `/mnt`.

I recreate the `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` folders:

```
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

I edit `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1 / defaults 0 0
```

I `chroot` into `/mnt`:

```
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

I install grub, recreate an `initrd`, and the grub configuration file: (`$(uname -r)` launched on physical server)

```
grub2-install --recheck --no-floppy /dev/sda
mkinitrd /boot/initrd.$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

I reboot ;

grub menu is loaded, I can choose system to get loaded, when I try `rescue` mode, I can reach the login interface ; the appropriate hostname get shown on my VM:

```
physical_hostname login:
```

However, I can't login (I am pretty sure having entered the appropriate password)

If I don't chose the rescue mode, the system does not fully boots: Here are the last lines printed:

```
[ OK ] Started show plymount boot screen
[ OK ] Reach target paths
[ OK ] Reach target basic system
... Here, I wait for like 2 minutes
dracut-initqueue[246]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
... This message gets prints like 100 times
[ OK ] Started dracut initqueue hook
[ OK ] Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[ OK ] Reached target Remote File Systems.
dracut-initqueue[246]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
A start job is running for dev-disk...225a.device
```

And it does not stop.

I'm pretty sure I close to boot my system; however I am totally stuck.
Many thanks for helping ; I'm feeling pretty desperate

Comment: You miss to tell us what is the target hypervisor, as if vmware, tool exist to do a p2v

Comment: Did you fix the /etc/fstab with the UUIDs of the filesystems in the target VM?

Comment: I just put `/dev/sda1 / defaults 0 0` into  `/etc/fstab` which seemed to be enough as the hostname gets correctly printed when I boot on rescue mode :/ Maybe this is not enough, however I have no idea how to get UUIDs of the filesystems

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a step-by-step detailed [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/988703/64325) of how I solved a very similar challenge on the question: [Turning a running Linux system into a KVM instance on another machine](https://serverfault.com/a/988703). I hope it proves a useful answer for this question too.

Goal of the answer: to take a physical Linux `P` node running live-production and virtualise it. Without having to create and allocate multi terabyte disks, nor have to use md raid in the `V` guest, because the target hypervisor (Proxmox 5) used ZoL/ZFS. Also wanted to mitigate downtime/reboots on the running `P` node.